# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2013 History View

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2013

I am migrating to CRM 2013 from version 4.0, and I am used to seeing a History entity under Contacts.  For whatever reason, I am not seeing that entity/view under Contacts.  And under Accounts, the History entity only allows filtering on upcoming activities (i.e. next 30 days).

Can someone point me in the right direction to resolve this?

Comment: Is this "History" entity a custom entity?  if so, it should have upgraded fine.  Or are you referring to the List of Activities regarding this contact?  screenshots of the old and new version of CRM will help here as the question is unclear.

Comment: I assume you are referring to the activity history navigation item. "History" is not an entity and your question is off topic on StackOverflow as it has nothing to do with software development.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are referring to the history tab below.

[image]

This is now the activities section.

[image]

You can get open and closed activities via changing the selected view. On the CRM I'm looking the filter on has a range of options, including; e.g. All, next 30 days, next 90 days, next 6 months.

Activities can also be presented in social panes which has different behaviour.

[image]

Comment: I suppose then I am having an issue with the "filter on" which only gives me All or forward looking ranges  (i.e. next 60 days)